# appengine python remote_api module object has no attribute GoogleCredentials

Tags: python-unittest, google-app-engine-python, remoteapi

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GoogleCredentials'

I have an appengine app which is running on localhost.
I have some tests which i run and i want to use the remote_api to check the db values.
When i try to access the remote_api by visiting:

```
'http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/remote_api'
```

i get a:

```
"This request did not contain a necessary header"
```

but its working in the browser.

When i now try to call the remote_api from my tests by calling

```
remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth('localhost:35887','/_ah/remote_api')
```

i get the error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dan/src/gtup/test/test_users.py", line 38, in test_crud
    remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth('localhost:35887','/_ah/remote_api')
  File "/home/dan/Programs/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 747, in ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth
    credentials = client.GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GoogleCredentials'
```

I did try to reinstall the whole google cloud but this didn't work.

When i open the client.py

```
google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/google-api-python-client/oauth2client/client.py
```

which is used by remote_api_stub.py, i can see, that there is no GoogleCredentials class inside of it.

The GoogleCredentials class exists, but inside of other client.py files which lie at:

```
google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/oauth2client/oauth2client/client.py
google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/oauth2client/oauth2client/client.py
google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/oauth2client/client.py
google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/oauth2client/client.py
```

my app.yaml looks like this:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest

builtins:
- remote_api: on

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

Is this just a wrong import/bug inside of appengine.
Or am i doing something wrong to use the remote_api inside of my unittests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by replacing the folder:

```
../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/google-api-python-client/oauth2client
```

with:

```
../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/oauth2client/oauth2client
```

the one which gets included in the google-api-python-client folder now has the needed Class: GoogleCredentials in the client file.

Then i had a second problem with the connection and now i have to call:

```
remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth('localhost:51805','/_ah/remote_api', False)
```

note, the port changes every time, the server gets restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Answering instead of commenting as I cannot post a comment with my reputation -

Similar things have happened to me, when running these types of scripts on mac.  Sometimes, your PATH variable gets confused as to which files to actually check for functions, especially when you have gcloud installed alongside the app engine launcher.  If on mac, I would suggest editing/opening your ~/.bash_profile file to fix this (or possible ~/.bashrc, if on linux).  For example, on my Mac I have the following lines to fix my PATH variable:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/google_appengine:$PYTHONPATH
```

These basically make sure the python / command line will look in /usr/local/bin (or /usr/local/google_appengine in the case of the PYTHONPATH line) BEFORE anything in the PATH (or PYTHONPATH).

The PATH variable is where the command line checks for python files when you type them into the prompt.  The PYTHONPATH is where your python files find the modules to load at runtime.

Comment: the answer helped me to look further for problems.
i noticed, that the paths you mentioned were already in my PATH variable. I tried to add google to the path, but it didn't include the right files. Simple replace of a folder worked, but its not a good solution...